# Get the NextHighest Version number out of Availble Version

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Assume that I have the 4 different Version

**After delete, refresh to next highest available case version.**

For example, if I delete Version 1.1 in this list, I would expect to have the page refresh to 1.2.
If I delete 1.3, I would expect to have the page refresh to 1.2.
If I delete 1.0, I would expect to have the page refresh to 1.1

```
public decimal GetLatestValidCaseVersion()
{
    return Versions
        .Where(b => !b.IsDeleted)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.DisplayVersion)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .DisplayVersion;
}
```

on the DisplayVersion, I'll get the latest version based on lastmodifiedutc....but I want it based on the above example.....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That code returns the highest non-deleted version, but doesn't compare it to any "current" version. How do you know what the current version is?

Comment: Even I dont know....how to write a logic for that....I'm a fresher...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to return the `DisplayVersion` of the first item in the list whose `DisplayVersion` is greater than the greatest `DisplayVersion` of the items where `IsDeleted == true`, unless none are greater in which case return the greatest of the non-deleted items, and if none are deleted then return the smallest `DisplayVersion`.

```
public decimal GetLatestValidCaseVersion()
{
    // Order the items by DisplayVersion
    var ordered = Versions.OrderBy(v => v.DisplayVersion).ToList();

    // Get all the non-deleted items (in order)
    var nonDeleted = ordered.Where(v => v.IsDeleted == false).ToList();

    // Find the item with the greatest DisplayVersion of all deleted items
    var highestDeletedVersion = ordered
        .Except(nonDeleted)
        .LastOrDefault();

    // If there are no deleted items, return the first DisplayVersion
    if (highestDeletedVersion == null)
        return ordered.First().DisplayVersion;

    // Otherwise, return the first non-deleted item whose DisplayVersion 
    // is greater than the greatest deleted item, and if none exist 
    // then return the last non-deleted item's DisplayVersion
    return (nonDeleted
        .FirstOrDefault(v => v.DisplayVersion > highestDeletedVersion.DisplayVersion)
            ?? nonDeleted.Last())
        .DisplayVersion;
}
```

Or an iterative way to do this (which would be more efficient) might look something like:

```
public decimal GetLatestValidCaseVersion()
{
    var ordered = Versions.OrderBy(v => v.DisplayVersion).ToList();
    Version latestValidCaseVersion = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < ordered.Count; i++)
    {
        var prevVersion = i > 0 ? ordered[i - 1] : null;
        var thisVersion = ordered[i];
        var nextVersion = i < ordered.Count - 1 ? ordered[i + 1] : null;

        if (thisVersion.IsDeleted)
        {
            if (nextVersion != null && !nextVersion.IsDeleted)
            {
                latestValidCaseVersion = nextVersion;
            }
            else if (prevVersion != null && !prevVersion.IsDeleted)
            {
                latestValidCaseVersion = prevVersion;
            }
        }
        else if (latestValidCaseVersion == null)
        {
            latestValidCaseVersion = thisVersion;
        }
    }

    return latestValidCaseVersion.DisplayVersion;
}
```